# Custom Made Windows Image - howto ensure that the Windows Key from BIOS is used

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-activation

I'm preparing a customized Windows Image.

I installed Windows 8.1 Pro (using the KMS Client Setup Key since I had to enter a key) and entered Audit Mode.

Which steps do I need to take to ensure that the Windows Image - after deployment - will activate using the key saved in the computers BIOS?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: Creating a PowerShell script which runs at the end of OOBE does trick:

```
$key = powershell “(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’).OA3xOriginalProductKey”
cscript C:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk $key
```

Have fun